# automapper automapping deep object to flat object and back

Tags: c#, automapper

How do you convert a deep object to a flat object and back using automapper?

for instance:

```
Person 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

Address
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}

FlatObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two ways you could accomplish this:

1. Define two mappings, one from `FlatObject --> Person` and another from `FlatObject --> Address`:

   ```
   Mapper.CreateMap<FlatObject, Address>();

   Mapper.CreateMap<FlatObject, Person>()
       .ForMember(dest => dest.Address, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));
   ```
2. Define one mapping and create the `Address` object inside the mapping definition:

   ```
   Mapper.CreateMap<FlatObject, Person>()
       .ForMember(
           dest => dest.Address, 
           opt => opt.MapFrom(
               src => new Address { City = src.City, State = src.State }));
   ```

Personally I'd go with option 1. This way if you add properties to `FlatObject`, you won't have to worry about updating the mapping definition (you would if you used option #2).

However, [@Raphaël](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18665741/497356) is correct in pointing out the author's link that questions the validity of mapping to domain objects.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from version 6.0.1 you can do with the ReverseMap method, wich is used to create the unflatten map.

```
Mapper
  .CreateMap<FlatObject, Person>()
  .ReverseMap();
```

This creates two maps, the flatten map is used to create the reversed one.

There is [detailed info at the automapper documentation](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well, AutoMapper is ok for "automatic" flattening, just respect the naming conventions, in your case

```
FlatObject {
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string AddressCity {get;set;}
  public string AddressState {get;set;}
}
```

But AFAIK, AutoMapper doesn't do unflattening .

See [this](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/09/18/the-case-for-two-way-mapping-in-automapper/) from the author of the library.

They're other tools that do that (with other kinds of limitations), like [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/)